# Different result for simple math in python 2 and 3

Tags: python

Can someone help me figure out why the same simple calculation gets different answers in python 2 and 3? The expression is  ​`(0.2**(-2)-1)**(1/2)`.

When I use python 2 in a Canopy IDE, I get `1`.

When I use python 3 in google colab, I get `4.98`.

In both cases I am literally running exactly the above expression. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer division works differently in Python 2 and 3.

For example (1/2) will return

`0` in Python 2, and

`0.5` (a float) in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you so much!